# Using Portable Class Library with a Universal Windows App for Win 10 (UWP) and Windows Service

Tags: wcf, service, portable-class-library, uwp

I am currently writing a Win 10 UWP project that provides administrative control for a windows service. I was unable to reference a standard class library that contains my model layer. This Model layer hold objects that I want to share with another project that is a Windows Service project. What is the best way to do this and can I create a UWP app as a standard long running Windows Service? Would I be better off porting the Windows Service to a WCF project and can a WCF run as a Windows Service? I'm confused with the new server offerings for Win 10 and Win Server 2016. The Windows Services that I wrote use custom protocols based on serialized objects with a binary serializer. Apparently that has changed as well with the new windows sockets models which seem to require that objects are serialized into a string. I'm very confused by all the recent changes and lack of Microsoft documentation. The only proper books that I found on Amazon are all for pre-order for the middle of next year.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem. The trick is to upgrade the Windows Service and it's layer projects from the 4.5.2 build to 4.6 and then use a portable class project for my model layer. Switching out Binary Serialization to JsonConvert and bang it works.